# select column from datatable and convert this to datatable again

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to select one column in an DataTable in C#, this column should be transform also in an DataTable.

This is what I want.

*DataTable(many columns) > select one column > convert this column to a DataTable again*

I have try this, but this give me the complete DataTable back.

```
DataTable dt = defindedDataTable.Columns[0].Table;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `DataView` from your table and then use the [DataView.ToTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx) Method. With this method, you can select one or more column you want:

```
DataTable dt = defindedDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, defindedDataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName);
```

Comment: Good one, Chris, I didn't know about `ToTable()`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I knew this method, but 30 min ago, I didn't know the overload that allow you to select columns ;-). Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new table, insert the single column, and populate with rows containing original data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = defindedDataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName,
    DataType = defindedDataTable.Columns[0].DataType,
    Expression = defindedDataTable.Columns[0].Expression,
    ColumnMapping = defindedDataTable.Columns[0].ColumnMapping
};
dt.Columns.Add(column);
foreach (DataRow row in defindedDataTable.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    newRow[defindedDataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName] = row[defindedDataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName];
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: hey DonBoitnott, this is a possible way, but I don't get the data from the defindedDataTable, is there something wrong

Comment: You will have to address a specific row to get data from the column, which your original example didn't show, so I've edited with a generic response.

Comment: i want the complete data of one column, do i need a for loop over all rows?